# How can I pass a vector to a function handle of the same size , so that it automatically takes the first input as the first variable and so on? MATLAB

Tags: matlab, function-handle

Assume I have a vector `A=[a1 a2 a3 ... an]`, and a defined function handle `f=@(x1,x2,x3,..,xn)`, how can I input the vector to the function handle without explicitly writing `f(A(1),A(2),...,A(n))`? The code I am writing gives me different `n` for different situations, and it is not practical to manually input the function parameters because it is of variable size.

Example:
I might get `f=@(x,y)(x^2+y^2)` and `A=[1 2]`, I can say `f(A(1),A(2))` and my problem is solved, but only if I have two variables. If I have `f=@(x,y,z)(x^2+y^2+z^2)` and `A=[1 2 3]`, I should write `f(A(1),A(2),A(3))`.

This may be rephrased probably as how can I control the number of the "slots" in the function handle the way I want?

Comment: Wolfie's answer solves your immediate problem, but you should really consider writing functions to take arrays as input. MATLAB is a vectorized language, it should not be used with lots of individual numbers, but with one or a few arrays of numbers. Your examples here are likely not the functions you are actually dealing with, but for example, `f=@(x,y,z)(x^2+y^2+z^2)` is the same as `f=@(v)sum(v.^2)`, except that the latter works for vectors of any length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go via a cell array

```
% Convert input array to a cell
A = num2cell( A );
% Deal the cell array to the inputs of f
f( A{:} );
```

Or you just write your function so that it indexes an array, rather than relying on multiple scalars, i.e. `f=@(x,y)x+y;` becomes `f=@(z)z(1)+z(2);`